# ORDER BY datediff() reversed with unnamed column in mariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

Example queries below, can you tell me why they return a different result? Specifically, why the order is reversed.

**There's only one difference between the two**: in the second query, the `datediff` in the select clause is named and re-used in the `ORDER BY`, while in the first one it is not named.

This is with mariadb 10.1.18 as well as 10.2.12.

**First query**:

```
select Start_Date, min(End_Date), datediff(min(End_Date), Start_Date)
from (
 select Start_Date 
 from Projects 
 where Start_Date 
 not in (select End_Date from Projects)
) a,
(select End_Date 
 from Projects 
 where End_Date 
 not in (select Start_Date from Projects)
) b
where Start_Date < End_Date
group by Start_Date
order by datediff(min(End_Date), Start_Date)
;

+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Start_Date | min(End_Date) | datediff(min(End_Date), Start_Date) |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-04    |                                   3 |
| 2015-10-13 | 2015-10-15    |                                   2 |
| 2015-10-28 | 2015-10-29    |                                   1 |
| 2015-10-30 | 2015-10-31    |                                   1 |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------+
```

**Second query:**

```
select Start_Date, min(End_Date), datediff(min(End_Date), Start_Date) as 'test_diff'
from (
 select Start_Date 
 from Projects 
 where Start_Date 
 not in (select End_Date from Projects)
) a,
(select End_Date 
 from Projects 
 where End_Date 
 not in (select Start_Date from Projects)
) b
where Start_Date < End_Date
group by Start_Date
order by test_diff
;

+------------+---------------+-----------+
| Start_Date | min(End_Date) | test_diff |
+------------+---------------+-----------+
| 2015-10-28 | 2015-10-29    |         1 |
| 2015-10-30 | 2015-10-31    |         1 |
| 2015-10-13 | 2015-10-15    |         2 |
| 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-04    |         3 |
+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Based on your results, your first query must have something like a `desc` in the `order by`.

Comment: It's a plain cut and paste from my session, no `desc` there. Adding `desc` actually shows the results in the expected order. Or is there something that causes an implicit `desc` here? The only difference is literally the `... as 'test_diff'` and use of `test_diff`.

Answer (score 0):

your second Query has

```
order by test_diff
```

and your first does not in you add this line to the first it will show as the second does.
if you change the order by on the second query to

```
order by test_diff DESC
```

it will look like the first, putting the result in DESCending Order

Comment: Both queries have an "ORDER BY" using the same values (obtained in different ways), with no other parameters. The order should be the same? Why is the order different?

Sure, if I make the queries the same, they will give the same order...

Comment: it reverts to the primary index of the main table if you don't use order by, its not random it will do as programed by who created the table on the first query it has "order by datediff(min(End_Date), Start_Date)"

Comment: Did you read my queries? There's an "ORDER BY" clause in both of them.

Comment: SorryI type that response in, an then erased it (I thought) and typed a different one because I did ready them. this is what I meant to say - I have worked with many flavors of SQL and I . have not seen that happen, because they are the same in both queries, except one is index with the aliased field, this is somthing specific to Mariadb that I am am not familier with. maybe some one else can help. in my book they equate to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug.  Please file a bug report.

Meanwhile, the problem can probably be worked around by making a subquery of most of the query, then doing the `ORDER BY` in the outside query.

Comment: Thank you. Just filed a bug https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15381. Let's see what happens.